# understanding OOP and extending a parent class while inheriting its properties set by internal logic

Tags: php, oop

I have been tinkering around with OOP and seeing how to go about doing this. I have parent class that does stuff and sets values to its own properties. Then I want to create a child class that extends the parent while "somehow" accessing the dynamically modified properties. I was wondering if this could be done with a proxy of some sort. Im still learning so i'm not 100% sure on the OOP strategies here.

```
class Parent
{
    public $test;

    public function boot()
    {
        // boot stuff
        $this->internalStuff();
    }

    public function internalStuff()
    {
        $this->test = 'World!';
        $c = new Child();
        $c->cTest();
    }
}

$p = new Parent;
$p->boot();


class Child extends Parent
{
     public function __construct()
     {}

     public function cTest()
     {
         echo 'Hello ' . $this->test;
     }
}
```

Comment: A sidenote (not related to your question): don't use reserved words like `Parent` for classnames, otherwise you'll provoke fatal errors in php.

Comment: You inheritance hierarchy is obviously wrong. Because `extends` stands for ***is-a***. Which means that in your mind, *every child is a parent*, which is kinda .. (lets go with) wrong. In OOP who have this thing called [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) .. here is a bit [dumbed-down version (image)](http://www.globalnerdy.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/liskov_substitution_principle_small.jpg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inheritance (parent/child relationships between classes) only extends to the class definition. I.e. what methods and properties a class has. It only defines the "blueprint" of a class. The actual *values* are assigned to *object instances* of the class. You cannot modify the inheritance of an instantiated object. Neither does one object magically take over the values of another object, regardless of how their parent/child relationship is.

So no, it just doesn't work that way. If you want a `Child` object to have certain values, you need to assign them to an instance of that object. Whatever you did with a completely different object instance of another class doesn't matter.

Comment: what if i pass the values to a static class then use it in a __get or __call method to retrieve the static counterparts?

Comment: That's a possibility, but it totally defies the purpose of OOP. `static` classes and properties are essentially global variables, which you should not use. Objects are supposed to be *self contained*.

Comment: what bout registries then?  noticed that they are all statically used

Comment: Yes, and registries are anti-patterns. You can search SO for registry vs. dependency injection discussions...

Comment: @Eli , well .. it's nice and all .. only, `static` classes are not really OOP. They are just global procedural code wrapped in a namespace, which just happen to look like a class definition.